# Socket IO client delays in firing connection event when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, socket.io, this

I'm using React on the front-end and Node.js on the back-end with Socket.io for websockets.

consider this:

I have this module here for my socket setup on the client side.

**socket.js**

```
export default () => {

 const socket = io(`${config.origin}/chat`);
  const getAllChatMessages = messages => {
    socket.on('get-chat', messages);
  };

  const updateChatHistory = lastMessage => {
    socket.on('new-message', lastMessage);
  };

  const sendNewMessage = newMessage => {
    socket.emit('new-message', newMessage);
  };

  const unregisterHandlers = () => {
    socket.off('get-chat');
    socket.off('new-messge');
  };

  return {
    getAllChatMessages,
    updateChatHistory,
    unregisterHandlers,
    sendNewMessage
  };
};
```

And I use it like so in my React Component

**Chat.js**

```
class Chat extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.client = socket();
    this.state = { chatMessage: '', chatHistory: [], today: new Date() };
  }
```

Note that everything *works*. However, there is some very weird behaviour and that is when I assign the value of `socket()` to `this.client` inside the constructor, I get a 7 second delay before the 'on-connection' event is fired on the server. But if I rewrite my constructor like so:

```
 class Chat extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    socket();
    this.state = { chatMessage: '', chatHistory: [], today: new Date() };
  }
```

that is, if I just execute the `socket()` function and not assign it to the `this.client` property, then everything is instantaneous.

Why is this ?? In both cases the

```
io(${config.origin}/chat);
```

is firing inside socket.js